# Javascript : how to pass value into function parameter?

Tags: javascript

**function retrieveHasilRawatJalan()**

```js
function retrieveHasilRawatJalan2(row, kd_klp) {

   var hasil_rawat_jalan2;

   var xhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       hasil_rawat_jalan2 = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
       document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "type of : " + typeof hasil_rawat_jalan2;
       document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "value of {'1' {'klp_id' : [" + hasil_rawat_jalan2[1]['klp_id'] + "]";
       document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "object size :[" + parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2)) + "]";
       document.getElementById("row_start").innerHTML = "start row : " + row;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "content : " + hasil_rawat_jalan2;
     }
   }
   xhttp.open("POST", "../lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code/" + kd_klp + "", true);
   xhttp.send();

   //start from here the code is the same.
   var number_of_row = parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2));

   addNewRow(number_of_row);

 }
```

`variable hasil_rawat_jalan2` contain JSON data and type of this variable is object,

i check type of variable hasil_rawat_jalan2, and call one of the data using this code

```
document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "type of : " + typeof hasil_rawat_jalan2;
      document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "value of {'1' {'klp_id' : [" + hasil_rawat_jalan2[1]['klp_id'] + "]";
      document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "object size : [" + parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2)) + "]";
      document.getElementById("row_start").innerHTML = "start row : " + row;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "content : " + hasil_rawat_jalan2;
```

the result is this:

type of : object

value of {'1' {'klp_id' : [HL-004]

object size :[8]

start row : 1

content : [object Object]

> the problem is when i put var number_of_row in function addNewRow() it
>   doesnt do anything. but it work if i put number directly like this
>   addNewRow(8). how to check the error?

Comment: addNewRow definition please.

Comment: Why do you parse an integer into an integer? `parseInt` serves to parse a number from a string. Have you checked the contents of `number_of_row` at the call site of `adNewRow`?

Comment: Why redefine `xhttp` after the `if/else` block? The else  becomes worthless (well they both do)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 hahaha, nice. yes thats my mistake i will delete the one outside the block. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is asynchronous (XMLHttpRequest is, actually). It means that `hasil_rawat_jalan2` is not yet defined when you try to use it, because AJAX request doesn't pause subsequent program execution. You need to move `addNewRow` into `onreadystatechange` callback and call it once response has become available:

```
function retrieveHasilRawatJalan2(row, kd_klp) {

   var hasil_rawat_jalan2;

   var xhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       hasil_rawat_jalan2 = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
       document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "type of : " + typeof hasil_rawat_jalan2;
       document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "value of {'1' {'klp_id' : [" + hasil_rawat_jalan2[1]['klp_id'] + "]";
       document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "object size :[" + parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2)) + "]";
       document.getElementById("row_start").innerHTML = "start row : " + row;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "content : " + hasil_rawat_jalan2;

       // Use hasil_rawat_jalan2
       var number_of_row = parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2));
       addNewRow(number_of_row);
     }
   }
   xhttp.open("POST", "../lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code/" + kd_klp + "", true);
   xhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot dfsq^^. I hope all the smart people kind and helpful just like you and other commenters